# Como consigo acessar elementos do thread main em outros threads?

Tags: c#, winforms

Eu estou com este erro

> A operação entre threads não é válida: controlo 'LblCheck' acedido a
>   partir de um thread diferente do thread onde foi criado.

```
 Task tarefa = Task.Run(() =>{

  }
  .ContinueWith(t => {
                    LblCheck.Text = "Programa pronto para ser usado!";
                    progressBar1.Value = 100;
 });
```

Como consigo acessar elementos do thread main em outros threads ?

Comment: Já ouviu falar da propriedade [`CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Não conhecia nao